# File not found in quicklisp

Tags: installation, common-lisp, jupyter-notebook, quicklisp

I am installing cl-jupyter, there is a problem in quicklisp like this:

```html
$ sbcl --load ./cl-jupyter.lispThis is SBCL 1.3.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
... initialization mode... please wait...
To load "cl-jupyter":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-jupyter
; Loading "cl-jupyter"
.........; cc -o /home/keys/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.debian-linux-x64/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel-tmpGHU3ALSV.o -c -m64 -fPIC -I/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.19.0/ /home/keys/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.debian-linux-x64/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel.c
/home/keys/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.debian-linux-x64/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel.c:6:17: fatal error: zmq.h: file not found
compilation terminated.
While evaluating the form starting at line 5, column 0
  of #P"/home/keys/cl-jupyter/./cl-jupyter.lisp":

debugger invoked on a CFFI-GROVEL:GROVEL-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100399C6A3}>: Subprocess (:PROCESS #<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 1>)
 with command ("cc" "-o" "/home/keys/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.debian-linux-x64/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel-tmpGHU3ALSV.o" "-c" "-m64" "-fPIC" "-I/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.19.0/" "/home/keys/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.debian-linux-x64/home/keys/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel.c")
 exited with error code 1

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry PROCESS-OP on #<GROVEL-FILE "pzmq" "grovel">.
  1: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating PROCESS-OP on #<GROVEL-FILE "pzmq" "grovel"> as having been successful.
  2:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
  4: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cl-jupyter"
  5: [RETRY                        ] Retry EVAL of current toplevel form.
  6: [CONTINUE                     ] Ignore error and continue loading file "/home/keys/cl-jupyter/./cl-jupyter.lisp".
  7:                                 Abort loading file "/home/keys/cl-jupyter/./cl-jupyter.lisp".
  8:                                 Ignore runtime option --load "./cl-jupyter.lisp".
  9:                                 Skip rest of --eval and --load options.
 10:                                 Skip to toplevel READ/EVAL/PRINT loop.
 11: [EXIT                         ] Exit SBCL (calling #'EXIT, killing the process).

(CFFI-GROVEL:GROVEL-ERROR "~a" #<UIOP/RUN-PROGRAM:SUBPROCESS-ERROR {100691C9F3}>)
```

As you can see,it says "quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/pzmq-20170403-git/grovel__grovel.c" can not be found.

so I am trying to find if there is a .c file in the original quicklisp package,but actually not.Why this problem happened,and hoe do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zmq.h is the file that can't be found. You have to install a library that provides that header file for the Lisp side to compile properly.

Comment: Yes,indeed.I just fix it by "sudo apt install libzmq3-dev"